# Is there a way to build WinRT projects that know which version of winmd file to use based on process architecture?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

It's really a pain to keep renaming winmd files based on the build configuration (x86,x64, ARM).  Is there an easy way to roll the three configs into one winmd file? or if not, what's the best way to configure the build to detect which version of the winmd file to use?

Comment: You are doing it wrong, the metadata doesn't depend on the platform or bitness.  Not on .NET (the original source), not on WinRT either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for a way to reference your native winmd files so that for each target platform of your Windows Store app project the correct version of the winmd file (x86, x64 or ARM) will be used.

The best way to achieve that (and the only way I know of) is to create an [extension SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh768146.aspx#ExtensionSDKs) which you can install in Visual Studio as an extension and will then appear appear in the `Add Reference` dialog under the `Windows > Extensions` category. Examples of such SDKs are [SQLite for Windows Runtime](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23f6c55a-4909-4b1f-80b1-25792b11639e) and [Bing Maps SDK for Windows Store apps](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb764f67-6b2c-4e14-b2d3-17477ae1eaca).

There's a walkthrough available on how to create such an SDK in both [C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj127117.aspx) and [C# or Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/jj127119.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Winmd files should be platform agnostic, there is quite literally no processor information in the files (especially if they're generated from either MIDL or C++/CX).